# Why bottom tabs are not getting highlighted as top tabs in ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

i have a problem with bottom `tabs` which is active but not highlighted with blue color.

you can see active top tabs has blue color (Tab Two).

[image]

Similarly when i click on bottom tabs(Tab Four, Tab Five), it does not get active color blue why?

here is full demo:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic4-angular-tabs-template-rag89y

please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you can manage it with

```
<ion-tab-button tab="tab2" selected="true">
```

See [Properties -> selectedTab](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tab-bar#properties)

Comment: if i add `selected` as `true` or `false` then for each `route` do i need to  toggle the state?

it is not manageable then.  please edit here to show the solution https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic4-angular-tabs-template-rag89y   what you are saying

Comment: I think the boolean should be dynamic based on the state.